# SQL Server: split text field into multiple lines based upon LEN rule

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have a table comprised of `ID`, `Notes`, LEN(Notes), and LEN/60

I need to break it up into chunks of LEN = 60, adding a new "LINE" column that increases by 1 for each line.

So:

```
1 | Super long text of 150 characters | 150 | 3
```

becomes:

```
 - 1 | 1 | Super long text of 150
 - 1 | 2 | characters is much more
 - 1 | 3 | manageable!
```

I created the LEN and LEN/60 data in case the segments value would be useful in some kind of loop statement.

Recursive CTE, loop, variable - I'm open to just about anything at this point!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: IMHO, you are making both data storage and data retrieval harder than they need to be.  SQL server can handle long text, and it's much easier to read and parse it in an application if it's all in one record.

Comment: Totally agree with you, Jen - unfortunately the application is driving this solution as it is built to handle multiple line items with length no longer than 60 characters per line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. CTE is the answer. Please try this.

```
WITH cte_base AS(SELECT ID
                    , 1 AS IDLN
                    , LTRIM(RTRIM(Notes)) AS Notes
                    , 1 AS Rownum
                FROM yourtable
), cte_re AS ( SELECT Id
                    , IDLN
                    , 1 AS StartPos
                    , CAST(60 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(Notes, 1, 60) + ' ', 60))) AS INT) StringLen
                FROM cte_base
                WHERE Rownum =1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT r.Id
                    , r.IDLN + 1 
                    , StartPos + StringLen + 1
                    , CAST(60 - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(SUBSTRING(b.Notes, StartPos + StringLen + 1, 60) + ' ', 60))) AS INT) 
                FROM CTE_re  r
                INNER JOIN cte_base b 
                    ON b.Id = r.Id and b.rownum = 1
                WHERE StartPos + StringLen <= DATALENGTH(b.Notes) 
)       
SELECT r.Id
    , r.IDLN 
    , UPPER(SUBSTRING(b.Notes, r.StartPos, r.StringLen)) AS Notes
FROM cte_re r
INNER JOIN cte_base b
ON r.Id = b.Id;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Wendy!  This is SUPER-close, but I'm encountering 2 problems:
1: Any row with more than 1 segment results in extra "blank" rows.  So, ID 1771 with length of 110 should result in 2 rows (IDLN 1 and 2), but results in 4, with the last 2 having blank Notes values
2: If I let your code run without specifying an ID, I receive Msg 530, "..maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion" error.
Can you assist me a bit more?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data?